# Android: Event ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED is not sent to my BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to do something after the the phone is put into charger. So I 
created `ChargingOnReciever`:

```
public class ChargingOnReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver { 
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
        context.startActivity(someActivity);
        Log.d(TAG, "Phone was connected to power");
    } 
}
```

and I want my receiver to listen to `android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED`, so I put this into manifest:

```
<reciever android:name=".ChargingOnReceiver"
          android:enabled="true"
          android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
    </intent-filter>
</reciever>
```

But `ChargingOnReceiver` is apparently not started when I put my G1 to charger 
(connect to my notebook via USB cable). Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's receiver, not reciever! It took me 5 hours to find this stupid bug. I think that the Android Eclipse plugin should do some syntax checking in the manifest xml.

Comment: i also wasted my one day on this issue

Answer (score 10):

For anyone trying to register receiver for "android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" and "android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED" , I would like to add :

> As part of the Android 8.0 (API level 26) Background Execution Limits,
>   apps that target the API level 26 or higher can no longer register
>   broadcast receivers for implicit broadcasts in their manifest.
>   However, several broadcasts are currently exempted from these
>   limitations. Apps can continue to register listeners for the exempted
>   broadcasts, no matter what API level the apps target.

The above two broadcasts are no longer in the list of these exempted broadcasts. Please refer the documentation below :

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions

Comment: What would be the best option to receive these events now?

Comment: I found a solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/75957174/578309

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not start an activity from a `BroadcastReceiver`.
2. Have you examined LogCat at the time you plug in the USB cable to see if there are any logged messages that might explain your problem?

Comment: 1. I am starting activity only for testing purposes, to see if onReceive is called.

2. Unfortunately I could't find anything helpful in the log messages...

Comment: @CommonsWare can u pls explain why should not we start activity from broadcast reciever

Comment: @user3233280: Rarely, if ever, will that be what the user wants, if you are popping up an activity not based on user input. The user may get very irritated if you interrupt their game, and they may get very dead if you interrupt their navigation app. If nothing else, use a full-screen `Notification`.

Comment: @CommonsWare  can u pls tell me i m going to show toast but i have not register reciver from activity while i have registered in my manfiest i m starting activity/showing toast from onRecive() using context but my app gets closed i think context is null thats why it crashed how can i got context if i register reciver in manifest ?

Answer (score 0):

We cannot receive `ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED` and `ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED` events on post android 8 as [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53085078/578309) , but still `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED`

```
private var chargingStateChangeReceiver: BroadcastReceiver? = null
private fun listenForChargeEvents() {
        chargingStateChangeReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
            override fun onReceive(contxt: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
                val status: Int =
            batteryStatus?.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1) ?: -1
        if (status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING
                || status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL)
              print('charging')
            }
        }
        context.registerReceiver(chargingStateChangeReceiver, IntentFilter(
            Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED)
        )
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onCleared()
        context.unregisterReceiver(chargingStateChangeReceiver)
        chargingStateChangeReceiver = null
    }
```