# Broadcast receiver for POWER_CONNECTED

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, manifest

I want to register the receiver in code.
In my manifest I have this:

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReceaver">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.POWER_CONNECTED" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

I read this 
[startActivity() from BroadcastReceiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849868/startactivity-from-broadcastreceiver) but it didn't works, the onReceive method doesn't get called, if I register in code it works great.

what is the problem ? why it doesn't works ? I register the broadcast receiver in code and it works perfectly but when it is registered in the manifest it doesn't. Does anybody had registered this kind of receiver in manifest ? or maybe the @Gubbel is just wrong and this can't be registered in manifest. Maybe is like the screen_on/off which must be registered in code and can't be registered in manifest.

any tips or explanations why it is not working is welcomed 
Thanks

Edit:
sorry I must be blind, I didn't see the action_ part

Comment: The link you gave already contains the answer. Use action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED"

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104372/android-event-action-power-connected-is-not-sent-to-my-broadcastreceiver it does exactly what you are trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied wrong action string...

this is the right receiver

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReceaver">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```